# Truth statements regarding invertible matrices

Tags: matrices, solution-verification, matrix-calculus

The question is as follows:

---

Suppose $\textbf{A}$, $\textbf{B}$, and $\textbf{C}$ are square matrices such that $\textbf{ABC}=\textbf{I}$. Which of the following statements are true?

1. $\textbf{C}^{-1} = \textbf{AB}$
2. $\textbf{C} = \textbf{B}^{-1}\textbf{A}^{-1}$
3. $\textbf{A}$ is invertible.
4. $\textbf{C} = \textbf{A}^{-1}\textbf{B}^{-1}$
5. $\textbf{C}^{-1} = \textbf{A}^{-1}\textbf{B}^{-1}$

---

So far I've determined that 1, 2, and 3 are the only statements that are true:

---

1. 

$$\begin{align*}
\textbf{ABC} &= \textbf{I}\\
\textbf{ABC}\textbf{C}^{-1} &= \textbf{I}\textbf{C}^{-1}\\
\textbf{AB} &= \textbf{C}^{-1}\\
\therefore \textbf{C}^{-1} &= \textbf{AB}
\end{align*}$$
Thus, statement 1 is true.

2.
$$\begin{align*}
\textbf{ABC} &= \textbf{I}\\
\textbf{B}^{-1}\textbf{A}^{-1}\textbf{ABC} &= \textbf{B}^{-1}\textbf{A}^{-1}\textbf{I}\\
\therefore\textbf{C} &= \textbf{B}^{-1}\textbf{A}^{-1}\\
\end{align*}$$
Thus, statement 2 is true.

3.
$$\begin{align*}
\textbf{ABC} &= \textbf{I}\\
\textbf{ABC}\textbf{C}^{-1}\textbf{B}^{-1} &= \textbf{I}\textbf{C}^{-1}\textbf{B}^{-1}\\
\textbf{A} &= \textbf{C}^{-1}\textbf{B}^{-1}
\end{align*}$$

Assuming $\textbf{A}$ is invertible,

$$\begin{align*}
\textbf{ABC} &= \textbf{I}\\
\textbf{BCA} &= \textbf{I}\\
\textbf{BC}\textbf{C}^{-1}\textbf{B}^{-1} &= \textbf{I}\\
\textbf{I} &= \textbf{I}
\end{align*}$$

Thus, statement 3 is true.

4.
False due to statement 2.

5.
False due to statement 1.

---

Is there anything I've missed in terms of calculations or matrix properties? Any form of clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually all of them might be true. F.e. $A = B = C = I$

Comment: @openspace "the statement might be true" is different from "the statement is [always] true".

Comment: I've just noticed that formulation is unclear. His job is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Careful: you're assuming that the inverses of the matrices exist. In question 1, for example, you've multiplied on the right by $C^{-1}$. How do you know it exists?

Instead, use the definition of inverse. Given a square matrix $M$, if $MN = I$, then we say that $N$ is the inverse of $M$, and we can call it $M^{-1}$. In question 1, you have $ABC=I$. Writing this as $(AB)C=I$, we see that $C^{-1} = AB$ *by definition*.

This problem stands out especially in question 3, where your argument is: "Assuming $A$ is invertible, then $A$ is invertible". Do you see why this doesn't work? Much simpler: $A$ is invertible because its inverse, again by definition, is $BC$.

For questions 4 and 5, it is incorrect to assume that $B^{-1}A^{-1} \neq A^{-1}B^{-1}$. It's true that they will be different in general, but your argument is insufficient. (As @openspace points out in a comment above, you might have $A=B=C=I$.) Instead, find a specific counterexample where the two sides are different.

Comment: Just thought I'd add a little something too - also note that ${\det(ABC)=\det(A)\det(B)\det(C)=1}$, so none of ${\det(A),\det(B),\det(C)}$ can be $0$, hence all three matrices are invertible (since they must individually have non-zero determinant)

Comment: @Théophile Ohhh that makes sense. For questions 4 and 5, isn't the fact that $\textbf{B}^{-1} \textbf{A}^{-1} \neq \textbf{A}^{-1} \textbf{B}^{-1}$ in general sufficient proof, as the relationship does not hold true all the time?

Comment: @Peter While that's true, it would be worthwhile explaining why. In a more advanced context, you could certainly use that fact without proof, but here, the question is more or less asking you to show it.

Comment: @Peter At the very least, it's vague to say "False due to statement 2." If you want a happy middle ground, say something like this: "False. By statement 2, $C=B^{-1}A^{-1}$, and in general it is not true that $B^{-1}A^{-1}=A^{-1}B^{-1}$."

Comment: @Théophile That actually makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much for the clarification!

Comment: @Peter Glad to help!